# Heterogenous sized vectors where the types "work elsewhere"

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a function that works on a vector with size known at compile-time (these are provided by the `vector-sized` package):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs #-}
module Test where
import Data.Vector.Sized

-- Processes vectors known at compile time to have size 4.
processVector :: Vector 4 Int -> String
processVector = undefined
```

Fine, but what if I don't want to process vector of ints, but a vector of vectors?

```
-- Same thing but has subvectors of size 3.
processVector2 :: Vector 4 (Vector 3 Int) -> String
processVector2 = undefined
```

Fine, but there each sub-vector is of a fixed size. I want a function where the subvectors can each be of a different size but still known at compile time.

We can do this with [existential quantifications](https://markkarpov.com/post/existential-quantification.html):

```
data InnerVector = forall n. InnerVector (Vector n Int)
processVector3 :: Vector 4 InnerVector -> String
processVector3 = undefined
```

Fine, but what if I want to return not a String but a vector of the same dimensions?

```
processVector4 :: Vector 4 InnerVector -> Vector 4 InnerVector
processVector4 = undefined
```

This does not work because the second vector might have differently sized subvectors from the input subvectors! **I want them known to be same at compile time.** (So the subvectors at index 0 have same size, subvectors at index 1 have the same size, and so on.)

Is this possible to achieve? If not, do you know of (or can you create) a data structure that makes this possible?

I am avoiding tuples because:

- My vectors will have size over 100.
- Vectors make general processing easy (using 0-based indexes), so my processing functions continue to work even if I add more items to my vector.
- I do indeed only want values of one type within the inner vectors (`Int` in the example).

Comment: The outer "vector" isn't really a vector. It's a heterogeneous list. Look at the `vinyl` package for the sorts of types you want. If you really need a flat representation in memory, you may have to fake that up with `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: @dfeuer Interesting! I don't care about memory representation (as long as querying is fast O(1)). Can you create an answer showing a vinyl example that processes an outer "vector" of size 4, where the inner vectors have sizes 1, 2, 3, 4? Currently the stuff shown in vinyl is somewhat advanced for me.

Comment: I smell an XY-situation... do the inner vectors always have sizes 1, 2 ...? Then it would be better to not use variable inner lengths at all, but a _triangular matrix representation_ for the whole thing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sorry about the confusion, but the 1,2,3,4 was only a silly example. In fact  I want flexibility here. (Picture an outer vector of size between 2 and 10, and the inner vectors of sizes anywhere between 2 and 1000.)

Comment: This would be nicely possible if the sized vector was not homogeneous, but a sized _dependent_ vector `DVec 5 F` where `F :: Nat -> Type` so that the first element of the vector is `v!!0 :: F 0`, the next one is `v!!1 :: F 1`, and so on. Then you could write `processVector4 :: Vector 4 F -> Vector 4 F` where using the same `F` ensures the same type, hence the same length for the inner vectors. Alas, this is not what we have available in Haskell right now, so we need a custom vector type like the one given by Stefan Holdermans below.

Comment: If you want that fast constant-time lookup performance, use `https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.13.0/docs/Data-Vinyl-ARec.html#t:ARec`. I don't have time to help out with details right now, but maybe someone else will fill in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using existential quantification you effectively hide the sizes of the inner
vectors. But if you want to write code with types that convey that you are
preserving those sizes, you don't want them hidden. Instead you want your types
to be loud and clear about them.

So, let's define some types that broadcast these inner sizes. Essentially, you
need your "vector-of-vectors" type to be a type of heterogenous lists that
restricts the elements of these lists to be vectors. For sure, there are some
libraries out there that can help you put together such a type, but here we'll
roll our own. Just because it's more fun to do so.

Let's start with enabling some language extensions and then writing some types for the inner vectors and their sizes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, InstanceSigs, KindSignatures, TypeOperators #-}

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

data Vector :: Nat -> * -> * where
  VNil  :: Vector Zero a
  VCons :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (Succ n) a

instance Functor (Vector n) where
  fmap f VNil         = VNil
  fmap f (VCons x xs) = VCons (f x) (fmap f xs)
```

Next up is our type of "jagged" matrices (i.e., a vector of variable-size
vectors). As said, this is just a specific type of heterogeneous lists:

```
data JaggedMatrix :: [Nat] -> * -> * where
  MNil  :: JaggedMatrix '[] a
  MCons :: Vector n a -> JaggedMatrix ns a -> JaggedMatrix (n : ns) a
```

There, that's it. The type of jagged matrices is indexed by a list that contains the sizes of the inner vectors. The outer dimension is not explicated in the type, but can simply be derived from the length of the inner-dimensions list.

Let's put it to work and write a dimensions-preservering
function. Here's an obvious one:

```
instance Functor (JaggedMatrix ns) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> JaggedMatrix ns a -> JaggedMatrix ns b
  fmap f MNil           = MNil
  fmap f (MCons xs xss) = MCons (fmap f xs) (fmap f xss)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's great, and it works! However it confuses me because `MNil` and `MCons` are only declared at the type level. They are never implemented anywhere, but they still "just work"! Can you expand the answer around this a bit?

Comment: @haskellHQ The GADT syntax used for defining `JaggedMatrix` introduces `JaggedMatrix` as a type constructor and `MNil` and `MCons` as data constructors. Hence, `MNil` and `MCons` are very much declared at the value level. No magic there. In data-type declarations the declaration and implementation of constructors coincides.